# How do I check if a page is html5-based in python?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to parse various pages on the web using `lxml` module, like:

```
def dom(self):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(self.content)
```

But it seems like I have to switch this `lxml.html` to `lxml.html.html5parser` in the case of html5 pages.

http://lxml.de/html5parser.html

So how can I determine if a page is html5-based?  Do I have to check the `DOCTYPE` char by char before parse it?

---

Edit:  I made a simple regexp to deal with this problem. It seems to work, but yeah, I'm still looking for some neat ways.  This solution breaks `sourceline` method.

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.html import html5parser

def dom(self):
    content = self.content
    if self._is_html5():
        elm = html5parser.fromstring(content)
        content = lxml.html.tostring(elm, method='html')
    return lxml.html.fromstring(content)

def _is_html5(self):
    return bool(re.match(r'^<!doctype html>', self.content, re.I))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to switch to using the HTML5parser only for HTML5 files. You can, and probably should, use the HTML5parser for all HTML files. Browsers always use an HTML5 compatible parser for all HTML files regardless of version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  but I found that parsing html5 files with `lxml.html` turns out bunch of garbled text.

Comment: @ernix, that's the opposite of what Alohci answered. Let me repeat the answer of Alohci: you should use html5parser also for non-html5 files, and not, as you say, use lxml.html also on html5.

Comment: @krawyoti, thank you.  but html5 is not compatible with old html.  Tag names have to be lowercase with html5.  In `html5lib` version "1.0b2" I can see `html5lib/inputstream.py: EncodingParser.getEncoding` parses `<meta>`, but not for `<META>` properly.

Comment: @ernix - Tag names in the text/html serialisation of HTML5 are not case sensitive. (They are for the application/xhtml+xml serialisation but the charset definition in the meta element is ignored anyway for that). The processing of `<meta` in inputstream.py is just part of the initial pre-scan of the input HTML. The charset can be later updated in startTagMeta in html5parser.py. The tag name is lowercased for that comparison by emitCurrentToken in tokenizer.py.

Comment: @ernix - I have to say though that inputstream.py does look bugged. The [HTML5 parser algorithm for the prescan](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#prescan-a-byte-stream-to-determine-its-encoding) does say that it should be matching "meta" ASCII case insensitively.

Comment: @Alohci, Oh...I'm sorry.  I have misunderstood about both xml/html5 syntax.